# Unable to update values in Realtime Database with Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing sign in and sign up page in Android studio using Firebase. I don't face any error while compiling the code but no data is shown into the Firebase Realtime Database.
I have implemented all the steps given in Firebase Docs, and even successfully connected the app with Firebase including adding dependencies and plugins. Please guide me as I am new to Firebase.

Sign IN Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView signuptext;
    Button loginbtn;

    TextInputLayout username_var, password_var;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginbtn = findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        password_var = findViewById(R.id.passwordtext_field_design);
        username_var = findViewById(R.id.emailtext_field_design);
        signuptext = findViewById(R.id.createaccount);

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        signuptext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);

                String password_ = password_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                String username_ = username_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

                progressDialog.setTitle("Login");
                progressDialog.setMessage("In Progess...please wait");
                progressDialog.show();




                if (!username_.isEmpty()){
                    username_var.setError(null);
                    username_var.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    if (!password_.isEmpty()) {
                        password_var.setError(null);
                        password_var.setErrorEnabled(false);

                        final String username_data = username_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                        final String password_data = password_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

                        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("datauser");

                        Query check_username = databaseReference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username_data);

                        check_username.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.exists()){
                                    username_var.setError(null);
                                    username_var.setErrorEnabled(false);
                                    String passwordcheck = snapshot.child(username_data).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                                    if(passwordcheck.equals(password_data)){
                                        password_var.setError(null);
                                        password_var.setErrorEnabled(false);

                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Register Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressDialog.show();

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Final.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();



                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });


                    }else{
                        username_var.setError("Email is not Registered");
                    }
                }else{
                    password_var.setError("Wrong Password");
                }
            }


        });

    }
}
```

SIGN UP Activity

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView logintext;

    TextInputLayout fullname_var, username_var, email_var, phonenumber_var, password_var;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    DatabaseReference reference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        fullname_var = findViewById(R.id.fullname_field);
        username_var = findViewById(R.id.username_field);
        email_var = findViewById(R.id.email_field);
        phonenumber_var = findViewById(R.id.phoneno_field);
        password_var = findViewById(R.id.password_field);
        logintext = findViewById(R.id.Signintext);

        logintext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    public void registerbuttonclick(View view) {

        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

        String fullname_ = fullname_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String username_ = username_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String email_ = email_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String phonenumber_ = phonenumber_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        String password_ = password_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();


        if (!fullname_.isEmpty()) {
            fullname_var.setError(null);
            fullname_var.setErrorEnabled(false);
            if (!username_.isEmpty()) {
                username_var.setError(null);
                username_var.setErrorEnabled(false);
                if (!email_.isEmpty()) {
                    email_var.setError(null);
                    email_var.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    if (!phonenumber_.isEmpty()) {
                        phonenumber_var.setError(null);
                        phonenumber_var.setErrorEnabled(false);
                        if (!password_.isEmpty()) {
                            password_var.setError(null);
                            password_var.setErrorEnabled(false);
                            if (!email_.matches("/^\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*@\\w+([\\.-]?\\w+)*(\\.\\w{2,3})+$/")) {


                                FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                                DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("datauser");


                                String fullname_s = fullname_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                                String email_s = email_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                                String phonenumber_s = phonenumber_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                                String password_s = password_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                                String username_s = username_var.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

                                Datastorage storingdata = new Datastorage(fullname_s, username_s, email_s, password_s, phonenumber_s);
                                reference.child(username_s).setValue(storingdata);

                                Toast.makeText(this, "Register Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                email_var.setError("Invalid Email");
                            }
                        } else {
                            password_var.setError("Please enter the Password");
                        }
                    } else {
                        phonenumber_var.setError("Please enter the Phone Number");
                    }
                } else {
                    fullname_var.setError("Please enter the Name");
                }



            }
        }

    }
}
```

Contact Model

```
public Datastorage() {

    }

    public Datastorage(String name,String username, String email, String phoneno, String password){
        this.name =name;
        this.email =email;
        this.phoneno =phoneno;
        this.password =password;
        this.username =username;
}


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }

}
```

![Text]([image: logcat ss])

Comment: Sorry, but there's **way** too much code here for us to efficiently help. In the `onCreate` of your main activity, try writing to the database with `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test").setValue(true);`. If that doesn't work either, none of the other code matters for the problem and I recommend updating the question. For this and more, I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example

Comment: I saw one mistake in your code, Your DataStorage is taking first phoneno then password, but in this line: `Datastorage storingdata = new Datastorage(fullname_s, username_s, email_s, password_s, phonenumber_s);` you are giving first password then phone no. You might need to check that

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Please refer to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69965008/firebase-database-not-display-any-data-in-the-console] (Firebase Database not display any data in the console)